Geometric Interpretation of Linear Independence and Cross Product
Prove that if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent, and $\vec{w} \times \vec{u}=\vec{w} \times \vec{v}=\vec{0}$ then $\vec{w}=\vec{0}$. Interpret geometrically.
Solution: $$\vec w\in \left \langle ~\vec u~\right \rangle \cap \left \langle ~\vec v~\right \rangle =\left \{\vec 0\right \}.$$
Question: This is a solution that my linear algebra professor presented to me. However, I would like to know if it is possible to find a solution solely using concepts of analytic geometry, along with a geometric interpretation of it... I know that with two linearly independent vectors, we have the formation of a plane, but I'm not sure what that implies when I have a vector whose cross product with these two vectors equals the zero vector.

The length of the cross product of two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is given by formula
$$|\vec{u}\times\vec{v}|=|\vec{u}|\cdot|\vec{v}|\cdot\sin\angle(\vec{u},\vec{v}).$$
Therefore, if the cross product of two vectors is the zero vector, it means that the angle between these two vectors is $0$ or $\pi$ (i.e., these two vectors are collinear) or one of these two vectors is the zero vector.
In your exercise, $\vec{w} \times \vec{u}=\vec{w} \times \vec{v}=\vec{0}$. Assume $\vec{w}\neq\vec{0}$, then $\vec{w}$ is collinear with $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, but $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent, so this is impossible. Therefore $\vec{w}=\vec{0}.$
